# Proof about pointwise $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be bounded and let
>   $$\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = L$$
>   Prove:
>   (a) If $L=0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) g(x) = 0$
>   (b) if $0<L<\infty$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) g(x)$ exists.
>   (c) $L=\infty$ then  then $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) g(x) = \infty$.

when we say exists of course this means limit is finite. 
I have the thought that this may be as simple as creating what ever type of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ I want and use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ as a proof.

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first of your question.

Comment: what should it be @GitGud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|f| < M$ be the bound. Then we have
**(a)**
$$|\lim_{x\to c} f(x) g(x)| \leq |\lim_{x\to c} M g(x)| = M |\lim_{x\to c} g(x) | = 0$$
Can you do (b) and (c) in a similar way?

Comment: Let f< M be the found, then we have

Comment: lim f(x)g(x) as x approaches c is less than or equal to lim Mg(x) as x goes to c = M lim g(x) as x goes to c = infinity..... for part (c)

Comment: @Dom Note you need $|f| < M$, $f < M$ does not suffice. Minimalistic notation would be $\Vert f \Vert_\infty < M$

Comment: @Dom You forgot $|\cdot|$ around it and you only proved $|a| \leq \infty$ which is true for any limit.

Comment: lim f(x)g(x) x goes to c is less than or equal to lim M lim g(x) as x goes to c = Mlim g(x) as x goes to c = some number between (0, infinity)

Comment: Please use MathJax to note that ($\$\text{\lim_}\{\text{x\to c}\}\$$)

Comment: how do i show that notation on the website so i can say things correctly

Comment: $|\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x) | \leq A$ is written by $\$\text{|\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x) | \leq A}\$$

Comment: ($\limf_{x\toc}$)

Comment: $|\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x) |\leq A$

Comment: so i just need to correct those mistakes now so that (b) and (c) do follow?

Comment: @Dom Please post your (corrected) efforts via an EDIT into your original question. This makes it much more readable (use double $\$\$\text{\lim_{x\to c} f(x)}\$\$$ for bigger parts) $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$$
And will help bring more overview to this. Then we can see further.

Comment: $$|\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x)|leq $$|\lim_{x\to c} Mf(x)|$$

Comment: im going to try and fix it some time soon @AlexR